# Selecting specific menu based on log in details in c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Hi i have 2 available menu for a web based application. What I want is that when the user is logged in as "Admin" admin Menu should appear and if the user is not admin another menu should appear. I created 2 separate pages for log in and on admin log in page admin menu appears but as soon as i click any other menu item it goes to the user based menu. i have been searching the net for solution and all i could find is menu item option which is not a option for my problem. I have a short due date to submit this project please help. Thank you.

Comment: Dude,put some code for faster solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below links might help you.Using SiteMap control.

http://highoncoding.com/Articles/165_Creating_Menu_Based_on_Role.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321637/How-to-get-the-Menus-Based-on-Role-in-XML-Format-a

Comment: i found a solution but i am unable to post before 8 hours. So i will post it by then .

Answer (score 0):

Hi i thought a bit more and found an alternative way of doing so. I just have to make a few tweaks in pages and check for the log in id session in the pages. In HTML i included both the menu and made them both invisible. Then after checking for user id "Admin" i made the required menu visible. I hope it is the right way.

HTML PAGE

```
   <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing ="0">
   <tr><td bgcolor="#000000"><!-- #include file = "../header.htm"--></td></tr>
    <tr id="emp" runat="server" visible="false"><td bgcolor="#000000"><!-- #include file =    "../menu.htm"--></td></tr>   
    <tr id="admin" runat="server" visible="false"><td bgcolor="#000000"><!-- #include file = "../Cmenu.htm"--></td></tr> 
</table>
```

C# PAGE

```
 if (Session["getloginid"].ToString() == "Admin" || Session["getloginid"].ToString() == "ADMIN" || Session["getloginid"].ToString() == "admin")
            {
                admin.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                emp.Visible = true;
            }
```